# How do I properly append one array to another in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I currently have 2 ndarrays in python where I use zip to get an index and iterate over both and append each cell from one to the other, similar to what is shown below.  I now want to convert this over to tensorflow and essentially remove the for loop completely.  I thought this would be easy, but I seem to be dealing with a lot of shape issues and figured it was time to post on SO to find out the right way to do this.

The shape of arr1 is (24,) and the shape of arr2 is (24,5)

This is the logic I'm trying to bring into TF.

```
for id1, id2 in zip(arr1, arr2):
  row = id2.tolist()
  row.append(id1)
  finarr.append(row)
```

I have tried a number of things, but my current implementation, which is below the error shown, still isn't working.

Error is:

> : ('all the input array dimensions except for the
>   concatenation axis must match exactly',)

Current code:

```
val = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(arr1, (-1, arr1.size)))
finarr= tf.concatenate([arr2, val], 0)
```

Am I going about this all wrong?  Is there a better way?

------- Edit --------

The below code seems to be a much more elegant way of performing the concatenation via numpy, but I still haven't found a tensorflow equivalent.

```
finarr= np.column_stack((arr2, arr1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand the dimensionality of `arr1`, and concatenate along the last axis. Here's a way to do it:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

arr1 = np.arange(24)
arr2 = np.arange(24 * 5).reshape(24, 5)
finarr_np = np.column_stack((arr2, arr1))

p1 = tf.placeholder(arr1.dtype, shape=arr1.shape)
p2 = tf.placeholder(arr2.dtype, shape=arr2.shape)
f = tf.concat([p2, p1[:, None]], -1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    finarr_tf = sess.run(f, feed_dict={p1: arr1, p2: arr2})

assert (finarr_tf == finarr_np).all()
```

Comment: Simply beautiful! I need to look into this a little more to wrap my head around it, but it works perfectly. Thanks!